# OpenGL grayscale texture draws on one screen but not another

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I have a sample code which draws 8 bit rasters to a window using QUADS (glTexImage2D w/ GL_LUMINANCE set for both pixel format and internal format).

PFD was initialized like this:

```
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
int iFormat;

hDC = GetDC( hWnd );

ZeroMemory( &pfd, sizeof( pfd ) );
pfd.nSize = sizeof( pfd );
pfd.nVersion = 1;
pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
pfd.cColorBits = 8;
pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
iFormat = ChoosePixelFormat( hDC, &pfd );
SetPixelFormat( hDC, iFormat, &pfd );
```

And the texture was initialized like this:
    glPixelStorei (GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

```
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexEnvf (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

glTexImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, width, height, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

The machine consists of one Matrox card, which is connected to one regular color monitor and two monochrome monitors.

Problem is, the application draws into any part of the window which is in the color monitor, but blanks on the monochrome monitors. These are configured to be 8-bit linear grayscale in the control panel, which works fine otherwise.

Be glad to hear your ideas on this...

Comment: The surface format might be the problem, I would like to see the opengl window setup for both monitors.

Comment: @akaltar: added some code, assuming you meant the PFD?

Comment: I believe your problem is in the PFD(yes I meant the PFD when talking about surface format). You are trying to assign RGBA into 8 bits, and I think that is your problem, you should use `PFD_TYPE_COLORINDEX`

Comment: @akaltar Why not post that answer as an answer? :)

Comment: I am not sure if it actually is the problem, I am just throwing ideas.

Comment: @akaltar That's a good lead, but doesn't that enforces me to create a color palette for just a simple intensity raster? Can you supply a reference on doing that?

Comment: One more question, do you use the same PFD setup for both monitors, or different for each one? If you use the same PFD, I think I was wrong, and the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Also you should check for errors with `ChoosePixelFormat` and `SetPixelFormat`, and maybe look at the value of `glGetError()`. Here's the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318293(v=vs.85).aspx) about `PFD_TYPE_COLORINDEX`

Comment: @akaltar: yes, the PFD was set once, after initializing the window.

Comment: You could try disconnecting the color monitor, and then starting your program, to see if that would make a difference, maybe you would get the pixel format appropriate for the grayscale monitor.

Comment: @akaltar: Only changing PFD_TYPE_RGBA to PFD_TYPE_COLORINDEX, with everything else as in the example, results in a constant half-saturated red image on the color display (gray on monochrome). Disconnecting the color monitor and rebooting didn't have any effect.